# one hot encoding issue

Tags: tensorflow, dtype

I have the following code which i am trying to achieve one hot encoding.

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((10, 1)))
hprev = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((10, 1)))
k = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=None, name="k")
y_op = tf.assign(x, x[k, 0].assign(1))
M_c = tf.concat((hprev, y_op), axis=0)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    pri nt(sess.run(y_op,feed_dict={k:1}))
    print(M_c.eval())
```

I get the error:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x_64' with dtype int32.

Yet, I have passed 1 as the value, which in my understanding is an integer. What I am doing wrong? I am still a beginner please. I am trying to implement this part of the formula in [LSTM](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)!

[image: lstm]

Comment: Can you please post the input as well as the expected output of your method?

Answer (score 0):

Your placeholder name is k but you feed value for x. Change from `feed_dict={x:1}` to `feed_dict={k:1}`.

Comment: true. but the issue remains